# Hashmap put the same value

Tags: android, kotlin, hashmap

I just want to ask why my `HashMap` is inserting the same value even if I put it inside a loop?

```
val parentMap = HashMap<String, Any?>()
val map = HashMap<String, Any?>()
orders.forEachIndexed { i, order ->
   map["id"] = order.id
   map["productName"] = order.productName
   map["quantity"] = order.quantity
   Log.i(TAG, "order=$order")
   parentMap["data$i"] = map
   Log.i(TAG, "map=$parentMap") // This parent map contains a same value from map...
}
Log.i(TAG, "map=$parentMap")
```

Did I forget something to put??
Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: put the `val map = HashMap<String, Any?>() ` inside loop

Answer (score 0):

So what you are doing here is assigning the map object to your parent map. The parent map stores the map object as a whole instead of the data. You will have to create a new 'map' object in every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I think "map" can be a reference variable. so it will insert the same values

Answer (score 0):

To sum up what everyone said here.

In java and kotlin all objects stored in a heap and all your variables only store **references** to the objects in heap:

When you are doing this: `parentMap["data$i"] = map`

Your keys, ex: `data1`, `data2`, `data3`... will point to an instance of the same map which you created here: `val map = HashMap<String, Any?>()`.

So everything that you do to your map:

```
   map["id"] = order.id
   map["productName"] = order.productName
   map["quantity"] = order.quantity
```

change only one map that you have.

To fix it you can put your map creation inside the loop.
Or I suggest you to use immutable style like:

```
orders.mapIndexed { i, order ->
    "data$i" to mapOf(
        "id" to order.id,
        "productName" to order.productName,
        "quantity" to order.quantity
    )
}.toMap()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the Map object outside the loop.

> val map = HashMap()

So it will create single map entry where as you need different map for parent map.

Now you are entering different values in your map but since all maps references are now pointing to same Map Object so all Maps in your parent map will be showing last entries made to map.

The Solution is to keep val map = Hashmap() inside the loop. So with each iteration a different map objects will be created containg different data as per the iterations.